# checkbox should be checked when i click anywhere on list using android

Tags: android, checkbox

I had used custom listview and took checkbox in that.All the scroll and everything got solved.I have used viewholder to put my checkbox and values in that.And I had used onitemclicklistener on list.But I want that when I click on the anywhere in list checkbox should be checked.As of now my checkbox is checked only when I click on specifically on checkbox. Please help.I have seen lot of examples but not getting anything such that.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit more with some code you have done yet ?

Comment: so in `onItemClick` the `checkbox` doesnt get check, but when you specifically press on the `checkbox` it got checked. Is this your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I will give some OverView, You can do with your Effort:

Add a `clickListener` to your `ListView`. In item click, you can get the `position` . You can use `setChecked` to  appropriate `checkbox` with this `position`